# how do i enable SuperTab plugin in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Hi i installed the neocomplcache script and its great but i want to use a feature its called SuperTab, and the documentation on the site i think its wrong but i know that somebody with .vimrc experience can help me.
The site is [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2620)

In the script's site there are a bunch of lines you can add to your .vimrc to get features, there is a line that i think its badly formated, and thats why it doesnt work when i add like it is, the line is this:

```
" SuperTab like snippets behavior. 
"imap <expr><TAB> neocomplcache#sources#snippets_complete#expandable() ? "\<Plug>neocomplcache_snippets_expand)" : pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"
```

I'll add the line with the paragraphs below and above it for context.

> " Plugin key-mappings. imap 
>   (neocomplcache_snippets_expand) smap 
>   (neocomplcache_snippets_expand) inoremap 
>   neocomplcache#undo_completion() inoremap 
>   neocomplcache#complete_common_string()
>
> " SuperTab like snippets behavior. "imap 
>   neocomplcache#sources#snippets_complete#expandable() ?
>   "\(neocomplcache_snippets_expand)" : pumvisible() ? "\" :
>   "\"
>
> " Recommended key-mappings. " : close popup and save indent.
>   inoremap   neocomplcache#smart_close_popup() . "\" "
>   : completion. inoremap   pumvisible() ? "\" :
>   "\" " , : close popup and delete backword char. inoremap
>    neocomplcache#smart_close_popup()."\" inoremap
>    neocomplcache#smart_close_popup()."\" inoremap
>     neocomplcache#close_popup() inoremap  
>   neocomplcache#cancel_popup()

How am i supposed to add it to enable that feature?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I understand the problem, but I'd do this:

```
" SuperTab like snippets behavior. 
imap <expr><TAB> neocomplcache#sources#snippets_complete#expandable() ? "\<Plug>(neocomplcache_snippets_expand)" : pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"
```

Comment: Yeah my explanation of the problem was bad, i know how to paste text, i wanted to know how to add that line to my .vimrc file because if i add it as it is it doesn't work, and i don't know what " i have to remove or if maybe is not one line but 3 different ones and i have to remove the " in all of them, i tried many combinations and nothing works.

Comment: I updated my answer. A quotation mark is a comment so you should remove it from the imap line.